# Eloquent firstOrCreate documentation or usage

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm attempting to seek a table to see if a column named "name" exists if so return the value and if not create that row with a null value i saw firstOrCreate but i cannot figure out how to use it for the life of me.

This is what i currently have, can someone lend a hand?

```
 class Settings extends Eloquent
        {
            protected $table = 'settings';
            protected $primaryKey = 'name';

            public static function get($settingName)
                {
                    return self::firstOrCreate(array('name' => $settingName));
//                    return self::select(array('value'))->where('name', '=', $settingName)->first()->value;
                }
        }
```

Comment: What are you getting as a result of invoking `Settings::get($settingName)` ? Any error messages? Or something that you do not expect?

Comment: I'm getting a MassAssignmentException name because the name I'm attempting to get doesn't exist

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The create() method does mass assignment and this is a big security issue, so Laravel has a protection against it. Internally it has guarded = ['*'], so all your columns will be protected against mass assignment. You have some options:

Set the fillable columns of your model:

```
class User extends Eloquent {

    protected $fillable = array('first_name', 'last_name', 'email');

}
```

Or set only the ones you want to keep guarded:

```
class User extends Eloquent {

    protected $guarded = array('password');

}
```

You may, at your own risk also do:

```
class User extends Eloquent {

    protected $guarded = array();

}
```

And everything will be unguarded.

Take a look a the docs: http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#mass-assignment

You also could use your Facade to call it:

```
 class Settings extends Eloquent
 {
        protected $table = 'settings';
        protected $primaryKey = 'name';

        public static function get($settingName)
        {
            return Settings::firstOrCreate(array('name' => $settingName));
        }
 }
```

Comment: the issue I'm having is when calling Settings::get('example'); and exam example doesn't exist in the database instead of creating it i get a MassAssignmentException of name

Comment: Also why would calling by my Facade be better than using self:: ?

Comment: You are in fact mass assigning, so you need to add `protected $guarded = [];` to your model, if you need to assign to all your columns.

Comment: im not attempting to mass assign all i want to do is if that name is not in the table already create a row with names value set to $settingName is that not what my code reflects?

Comment: `create()` method does mass assignment by itself. Have you tested setting the guard var?

Comment: I have not what column would i guard the table only contains the timestamp columns a name and value columns?

Comment: Start by guarding nothing (`$guarded = [];`), to test mate. Then you move to what you really need.

Comment: Nevermind i see what you meant, and that worked perfectly, could you share why that made it work so i'll know in the future?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40005/discussion-between-clark-t-and-antonio-carlos-ribeiro)