# Insert Ignore Laravel 4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I want to do an insert in the database, but I want to make an insert ignore, to ignore if there is already a value in the primary key. How do I do this with eloquent? this is my code in eloquent:

```
return LogMonth::insert(array('users_id'  => $user,
                         'log'       => $Log,
                         'month'     => $Month,
                         'year'      => $Mear,));
```

Comment: You want to log an error? Or did you call your eloquent model `Log`? If so you cold get into trouble with the error logging: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/errors I recommend the laravel documentation about inserting using eloquent: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#insert-update-delete

Comment: I want to add a line to log, is not an error table

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `firstOrCreate` method:

```
return Log::firstOrCreate([
    'users_id'  => $user,
    'log'       => $Log,
    'month'     => $Month,
    'year'      => $Year,
]);
```

Comment: Yes, but If I use this method, I have this error: Illuminate \ Database \ Eloquent \ MassAssignmentException 
users_id

Comment: You need to create a `$fillable` array on your model for columns that may be mass assigned. See http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#mass-assignment

Comment: Yes, but I want to do an insert in the database, but I want to make an insert ignore

Comment: yes then `firstOrCreate` is the way to go. It will insert your data and ignore it if the `users_id` already exists. Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19592160/eloquent-firstorcreate-documentation-or-usage

Comment: Actually no, firstOrCreate() will look for that exact combination of attributes, not just user_id. As you can see in Model.php it calls:
    static::where($attributes)->first()

Comment: @ivanhoe - The OP is unclear. "if there is already a value in the primary key" could mean what you think it does, but I thought not. Whatever...

Comment: This also isn't as memory efficient.